# Bootstrap tooltip lingers when attaching to body

Tags: jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-events, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have an edge case when applying bootstrap 3 tooltips to a specific div under body.

```
 $('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-tt="tooltip"]', container: '.spa > div:first-child', trigger: 'hover', delay: { show: 500, hide: 0 }, placement: function () {
     var position = this.$element.data('placement');
     if (typeof position !== 'undefined') {
       return position;
     } else {
       return 'bottom';
     }
}});
```

I apply the tooltip to a, i, input, button, divs - and it works great on hover. When I hover on input/button then click, then `mouseout` - the tooltip will stick on the dom if I time this edge case perfectly. I don't have site to share, but my question is how would I clean up BS3-Tooltips ON BODY if its not an option to track the history of every dom element with a tooltip?

I couldnt simply do a `...tooltip(...).on('click', function(this) { ...('hide'); } ..`. because the context is always body. And I need to place the tooltip inside that .spa for clearing all tooltips easily on routing.

P.S. I have tried removing animation, delays.

Comment: so far, if I add an on click event handler to the body, and clear all the tooltips that way, it seems to take care of my edge case. It makes sense, since it was on click that the tooltip lingered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', function () {
    $('body').tooltip('hide');
}).tooltip({selector: '[data-tt="tooltip"]', container: '.spa > div:first-child', trigger: 'hover', delay: {show: 500, hide: 0}, placement: function () {
    var position = this.$element.data('placement');
    if (typeof position !== 'undefined') {
        return position;
    } else {
        return 'bottom';
    }
}});
```

worked for me.